# How do I cycle through keys/values in a python dictionary using a for loop and if statement with user input?

Tags: python

This is my first question, so thanks for taking the time to read this.
In Python, I want to create an app that allows the user to answer questions about a product and then show that product if it matches all the correct attributes.
1) So it should ask the user..."Pick a brand?
2) If they get it right, then it'll say "Pick a color?"
3) If they get it right, then it should say "Product Available."
4) If at any point they choose a brand or color that isn't available it will show not available.

Here is what I did so far.

```
tshirts = [{'brand':'Hanes', 'color':'black'},
      {'brand':'Hurley', 'color':'red'}]

brand = input("Search a tshirt brand: ")
color = input("Search color: ")

for tshirt in tshirts:
    if tshirt["brand"] == brand:
        print(tshirt)
        print("Available")
    else:
        print("Not available")
```

So I don't know how to tell it once the user types in "Hanes" to then ask for the color and if the user types in "black" it should return "the product is available." If they choose "orange" it should say "Not available."

Again, thanks for reading this and hopefully once I learn more I can be the one contributing and answering questions!

Answer (score 0):

I used a list comprehension as a shorter way of doing your for loop, then just did a ternary operator to test if the color of the dictionary is the same as the specified color. If you have multiple colors in a list for the colors, just replace the `==` in the ternary operator with `in`

```
tshirts = [{'brand':'Hanes', 'color':'black'},
      {'brand':'Hurley', 'color':'red'}]

brand = input("Search a tshirt brand: ")
color = input("Search color: ")

shirt = [t for t in tshirts if t['brand'] == brand][0]
print("Available" if shirt['color'] == color else "Unavailable")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!!! What does the [0] represent? The 1st item in each dictionary/list?

Comment: @Case The first element in the list of dictionaries where the brand is equal to the given brand. There probably would only be 1 shirt for each given brand, so I just assume the list will only have 1 element, which is the shirt that you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you have created "tshirts" is a list. It is not a dictionary. Try creating a dictionary or data frame using pandas and then you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. Just change the latter part of your code to this:

```
for tshirt in tshirts:
if tshirt["brand"] == brand:
    print(tshirt)
    if tshirt["color"] == color:
        print("Available")
    else:
        print("Not available")
else:
    print("Not available")
```

Once you've checked the brand is available, you check in that if segment, if the color is available and then print accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simpler answers, I guess rest best of the answers have already been given.

```
tshirts = [{'brand':'Hanes', 'color':'black'},
      {'brand':'Hurley', 'color':'red'}]

resDict = {}
hasKey = False
brand = input("Search a tshirt brand: ")
for tshirt in tshirts:
    if tshirt["brand"] == brand:
        hasKey = True
        resDict = tshirt
        break
if hasKey:
    if resDict['color']==input("Search color: "):
        print("Available")
    else:
        print("Not Available")
else:
    print("Not available")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have created "tshirts" is a list. It is not a dictionary. Try creating a dictionary or data frame using pandas and then you can achieve what you want.

```
tshirts = {
    "Hanes": {'colors':['black','blue','red']},
     "Hurley": {'color':['red','green']}
}
```

## You can even have a list of colors for a brand as above

```
brandinput=input("Search Brand")
if brandinput in tshirts.keys():
    print(brandinput+" available in colors",tshirts.get(brandinput)['colors'])

colorinput=input("Select Color:")
if colorinput in tshirts.get(brandinput)['colors']:
    print("Color available")
else: print(colorinput," color not available")
else:

print(brandinput+" not available")
```